# Clustering comet backend

Tags: nginx, redis, comet

**Our problem:** we have more than 300 000 online clients to application (50 000 to one node). Because we use load balancer **we don't now where (which nginx instance) alive connection to client**. So we need pub message to all nodes.
**How we can get linear scalability?**

Current functionality:

- Comet(for us comet is required) clients (mobile/web browsers) and server (java) with pub-sub functionality.
- Client can send notifications to other (single) client;
- Server can send notifications to single client or group of clents;
- Clients recieve information about active clients (by group) from nginx+memcached

Now we use: nginx + https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module + memcached.

Client before set up on comet channel send request to server: "I am alive and my commet channel id ...". Each 10 min client reopen pipeline, but register as alive on server only once (it's other problem).

I think we can write some logic with Lua on nginx(+redis or memcached). And each client request for reopen pipeline update information in redis (+add additional information about nginx instance ip which bind connection). 
But may be exist other variants or practice for scalability comet functionality?